# Placeholder cursor color - Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, colors, placeholder

[image]

My question is about this image. When i have a placeholder in firefox, the cursor ( the vertical bar when we focus the input) turns black instead of white (my font color). [1st Image, it's not easy to see, but i have focus on "Password" input, and there's the black cursor]

If the input does no have a placeholder the bar is white as it should be. [2nd Image]

Is there anyway i can make that bar white?

Thanks

Edit [Code]:

CSS

```
input, select {
    background-color: #232323;
    margin: 3px 0px;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="right" /><br/>
<input type="password" name="passord" placeholder="Password" class="right" /><br/>
```

That's the code i'm using, the objective is to make that vertical bar in the top image [password field] be white.

Comment: Code? (`catch CommentTooShortException e`)

Comment: Sorry, i didnt understand your question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Please provide some code. How can we help if we don't know what you have?

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look at it when I have time

Comment: Confirmed with Firefox (Palemoon 15.4). No problem on Chrome. Here's a fiddle for you to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/J7Z4U/

Comment: Thanks for making the fiddle! If anyone knows a solution let me know :)

Comment: I have exactly this same problem with Firefox.  The cursor changes color only once you start entering text.

Comment: indeed, unfortunatly it seems no one found a solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is a bug in firefox. It's been detected in v15, and should be fixed in v19 (that's why it's marked as fixed at the moment):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769405

Nothing you can do but wait I'm afraid...